# Elasticsearch update mapping for type within index and reindexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

I've got an index called business_data which contains different types:
Clients, Messages, Events etc... each one of these has its own mappings, analyzers, etc.
I need to update the mapping for clients and reindex (reimport from activerecord, for example), without downtime. I've found a couple of articles online regarding zero downtime (create a new index, update the alias to direct to the new index, delete old index). These solutions discuss changing the entire index which means my entire business data... I only need to update the type.
Is there a way to create a new type and simply change the alias?
Any other suggestions on how to do it?
Its a Ruby on rails app and I'm using elasticsearch-rails.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe aliasing and reindex is the cleanest solution for doing what you want to achieve

Comment: @Yossi Chen which version ES you are using?  In ES 5.x it is not possible re-indexing partial data.

Comment: @avr we're using 1.6